# table lock while creating table using select

Tags: mysql

Using mysql version 5.0.18
I am creating a table TT,
Client 1
set autocommit = false;
start transaction
Create table TT select * from PT;

PT has tow columns pk bigint not null,name varchar(20)

Client 2
set autocommit = false
start transaction
insert into PT values(123,'text');
 While inserting a row in PT , it is waiting for the table Client 1 to commit. I am unable to insert the row. why? Is it possible to insert the row without waiting for Client 1 to commit.

Comment: Is it an isam table or innodb?

Comment: They are innodb tables. It works fine in mysql v5.1 but is there any other way to implement the use case in 5.0.18

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, MySQL locks tables sometimes, even during a select statement.  Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html) for more info if you are interested.  But it seems to say that InnoDB tables use row-level locking, while many other table types use table-level locking.  You can see what you have by typing `show table status from dbname`.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**:  Of course, having said that, I went to test my understanding and I was wrong.  It locks regardless of whether it is isam or innodb.